stop flutter_background_service when app is down (flutter)
Can't leave the background service. Give me a solution, please.
service_background.dart:
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
Future<bool> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
      title: "SMS to Email Service",
      content: "Ожидаю входящие СМС...",
    );

    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    print("Stopping service...");
    service.stopSelf();
  });



main.dart:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _requestPermissionsAndInitializeService();
  runApp(const App());
}

Future<void> _requestPermissionsAndInitializeService() async {
  await Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.request();
  await initializeService();
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print("AppLifecycleState changed: $state");
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      print("App is detached. Stopping service...");
      stopService(); // Остановка фоновой службы при закрытии приложения
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('Disposing widget...');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    stopService(); // Остановка фоновой службы при уничтожении виджета
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


I get the error:
The method 'stopService' isn't defined for the type '_AppState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'stopService'.
No idea how to leave a background service when closing the app.

You need to define stopService function first and pass a message to the background service to stop itself.
In the code you are listening to "stopService" message to stop the service so we need to send this message.
void stopService(){
   FlutterBackgroundService().invoke("stopService");
}

